# Activate WinXP Pro downloaded from MSDN with a retail license key

Tags: windows-xp, license

I've rebuilt an old laptop for a friend that had WinXP Pro installed. I downloaded an ISO from my MSDN subscriber account because I figured that's a safe and legal way to get the ISO, and I'd just use the license key from the label on the bottom of the (Dell, FWIW) laptop.

However, using that license key I just get errors about it being invalid.

The download wasn't marked as a volume license edition or anything, but could it be they've done something to the MSDN ISO such that it can't be used with even a legal retail key?

Do I need to find somewhere to download a "safe" *retail* ISO and start over?

Comment: MDSN images require MSDN keys (especially in the XP days), you'll need an ISO that matches the key type (retail for retail, OEM for OEM). If you're going to make them suffer XP, perhaps just install a windows-alike Linux distro (Mint or alike) instead. ;)

Answer (score -1):

From bitter experience, I understand that Dell laptops use a custom build image, which pulls the key from the BIOS (or somewhere else hard-coded). I think your only option is to aquire a Dell XP Pro installation CD...

Comment: Actually, all OEM installs of windows get their key from the BIOS, that key is marked as OEM and cannot be used to activate a retail Windows version. I have this problem on a Lenovo with Win 7 bought a few weeks ago.

Comment: @NathanShiraini "Actually, all OEM installs of windows get their key from the BIOS" As someone who worked for an MS OEM for years , this is not true.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The only laptops that have a Windows key embedded in them is machines that came with Windows 8 or greater.  Which is 100% irrelevant for a question on how to install Windows XP on a machine with a MSDN license key.  Windows XP machines **NEVER** had a license key embedded, **it was not possible to even do that**, when Windows XP were sold.

Comment: @ramhound I'm quite possibly wrong about but windows xp, but my win7 dell 100% has it stored internally. I have reinstalled it multiple times using install DVDs from various ...sources... and it picks up the key without me entering it. It's at least true from windows 7.

Comment: @THRND - Windows 7 license keys were never stored in firmware.  The machines that came with Windows 7 don't even have that capability.